# Setting negative margin for one line

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Locality] For two fields $A(z)$ and $B(w)$, the followings are equivalent:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $A(z)$ and $B(w)$ are local, i.e. $(z-w)^N[A(z), B(w)]=0$ for large $N$.
        \item $\displaystyle [A(z), B(w)] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \partial_w^{(j)} \delta(z-w) \gamma_n(w)$.
        \item \begin{align*}
        A(z)B(w) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \iota_{z,w} \frac{1}{(z-w)^{n+1}} \gamma_n(w) + :A(z)B(w): \\
        (-1)^{|A||B|} B(w)A(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \iota_{w,z} \frac{1}{(z-w)^{n+1}} \gamma_n(w) + :A(z)B(w):.
        \end{align*}
    \end{itemize}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

The output of this code is:
[image]

I want to remove the blank line marked in red. So I tried to write down `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before the `align*` environment. This gives the following weird result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `\begin{align*}` to `\quad$\begin{aligned}[t]` and `\end{align*}` to `\end{aligned}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Locality] For two fields $A(z)$ and $B(w)$, the followings are equivalent:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $A(z)$ and $B(w)$ are local, i.e. $(z-w)^N[A(z), B(w)]=0$ for large $N$.
        \item $\displaystyle [A(z), B(w)] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \partial_w^{(j)} \delta(z-w) \gamma_n(w)$.
        \item \quad$\begin{aligned}[t]
        A(z)B(w) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \iota_{z,w} \frac{1}{(z-w)^{n+1}} \gamma_n(w) +{} :A(z)B(w): \\
        (-1)^{|A||B|} B(w)A(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \iota_{w,z} \frac{1}{(z-w)^{n+1}} \gamma_n(w) +{} :A(z)B(w):\,.
        \end{aligned}$
    \end{itemize}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```